# Can't print out minesweeper correctly if guessing row or column 0

Tags: java, arrays, printing, minesweeper

Hey All I'm having some issues with my minesweeper code:

```js
public class MineSweeper {

  /**
   * This is the main method for Mine Sweeper game!
   * This method contains the within game and play again loops and calls
   * the various supporting methods.
   *  
   * @param args (unused)
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Variable Declaration
    String promptWidth = "What width of map would you like (3 - 20): ";
    String promptHeight = "What height of map would you like (3 - 20): ";
    String promptRow = "row: ";
    String promptColumn = "column: ";
    int mapWidth = 0;
    int mapHeight = 0;
    int userRow = 0;
    int userColumn = 0;
    int numberOfMines = 0;
    int adjacentMines = 0;
    String endGame = " ";
    boolean continueGame = false;
    char adjacentMinesChar = 0;
    boolean NoSafeLocations = false;


    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); //initialize scanner
    Random randGen = new Random(Config.SEED); //initialize random generator


    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!"); //Welcome message 

    do {
      boolean userWin = false;
      boolean userLoss = false;
      //user prompts for map sizing
      mapWidth = promptUser(scnr, promptWidth, Config.MIN_SIZE, Config.MAX_SIZE);
      mapHeight = promptUser(scnr, promptHeight, Config.MIN_SIZE, Config.MAX_SIZE);
      System.out.println();

      //creation of the board
      char[][] map = new char[mapHeight][mapWidth]; //initializing the map array with the user input width and height
      eraseMap(map); //map creation
      boolean[][] mines = new boolean[mapHeight][mapWidth];
      numberOfMines = placeMines(mines, randGen); //initializes the mines and brings back number of them

      while (userWin == false && userLoss == false) { //game loop begins and continues until player either wins or loses
        System.out.println("Mines: " + numberOfMines); //prints out number of mines
        printMap(map);

        //User play begins
        //user selects a field to sweep
        userRow = promptUser(scnr, promptRow, 1, (mapHeight)) - 1;
        userColumn = promptUser(scnr, promptColumn, 1, (mapWidth)) - 1;
        if (mines[userRow][userColumn] == true) { //if user selects mine he loses end of the game
          map[userRow][userColumn] = Config.SWEPT_MINE;
          showMines(map, mines);
          printMap(map);
          System.out.println("Sorry, you lost.");
          userLoss = true;
        } else { //if user selects a mine free field the play continues 
          adjacentMines = sweepLocation(map, mines, userRow, userColumn);
          if (adjacentMines == -2) { //if user selects a previously selected field just reprinting the map
            printMap(map);
          } else if (adjacentMines == -1) { //if user selects a field with a mine all mines shown
            showMines(map, mines);
          } else {
            if (adjacentMines == 0) { //if a user selects a field with no nearby mines
              sweepAllNeighbors(map, mines, userRow, userColumn);
            } else { //if a user selects a field with some nearby mines
              printMap(map);
            }
            //Checks if all locations without mines have been swept if so user wins and the loop is broken
            NoSafeLocations = allSafeLocationsSwept(map, mines);
            if (NoSafeLocations == false) {
              System.out.println();
            }
            if (NoSafeLocations == true) {
              showMines(map, mines);
              printMap(map);
              System.out.println("You Win!");
              userWin = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      //Ending the game
      System.out.print("Would you like to play again (y/n)? ");
      endGame = scnr.next().trim().toLowerCase();

      if (endGame.charAt(0) == 'y') { //if user inputs a word starting with y - the game continues
        continueGame = true;
      } else { //if user enters a character other than y the game ends
        continueGame = false;
      }
    } while (continueGame == true);
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing Mine Sweeper!"); //goodbye statement
  }


  /**
   * This method prompts the user for a number, verifies that it is between min
   * and max, inclusive, before returning the number.  
   * 
   * If the number entered is not between min and max then the user is shown 
   * an error message and given another opportunity to enter a number.
   * If min is 1 and max is 5 the error message is:
   *      Expected a number from 1 to 5.  
   * 
   * If the user enters characters, words or anything other than a valid int then 
   * the user is shown the same message.  The entering of characters other
   * than a valid int is detected using Scanner's methods (hasNextInt) and
   * does not use exception handling.
   * 
   * Do not use constants in this method, only use the min and max passed
   * in parameters for all comparisons and messages.
   * Do not create an instance of Scanner in this method, pass the reference
   * to the Scanner in main, to this method.
   * The entire prompt should be passed in and printed out.
   *
   * @param in  The reference to the instance of Scanner created in main.
   * @param prompt  The text prompt that is shown once to the user.
   * @param min  The minimum value that the user must enter.
   * @param max  The maximum value that the user must enter.
   * @return The integer that the user entered that is between min and max, 
   *          inclusive.
   */
  public static int promptUser(Scanner in , String prompt, int min, int max) {
    //initialize variables
    Integer userInput = 0;
    boolean userInteger = false;

    System.out.print(prompt); //prompts the user for input
    userInteger = in .hasNextInt();

    while (userInteger == false) { //checks if user input is an integer if not prints out an error
      System.out.println("Expected a number from " + min + " to " + max + "."); in .nextLine();
      userInteger = in .hasNextInt();
    }
    while (userInteger == true) { //if user in put is an integer checks that it fits between allowed min and max
      userInput = in .nextInt();
      while (userInput > max || userInput < min) {
        System.out.println("Expected a number from " + min + " to " + max + "."); in .nextLine();
        userInteger = in .hasNextInt();

        while (userInteger == false) { //if user didn't fit between min and max checks again for integer input
          System.out.println("Expected a number from " + min + " to " + max + "."); in .nextLine();
          userInteger = in .hasNextInt();

        }
        userInput = in .nextInt(); in .nextLine();
      }
      userInteger = false;
    }

    return userInput; //returns user input
  }

  /**
   * This initializes the map char array passed in such that all
   * elements have the Config.UNSWEPT character.
   * Within this method only use the actual size of the array. Don't
   * assume the size of the array.
   * This method does not print out anything. T his method does not
   * return anything.
   * 
   * @param map An allocated array. After this method call all elements
   *      in the array have the same character, Config.UNSWEPT. 
   */
  public static void eraseMap(char[][] map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
        map[i][j] = Config.UNSWEPT;
      }
    }
    return; //sets up a clean map array
  }

  /**
   * This prints out a version of the map without the row and column numbers.
   * A map with width 4 and height 6 would look like the following: 
   *  . . . .
   *  . . . .
   *  . . . .
   *  . . . .
   *  . . . .
   *  . . . .
   * For each location in the map a space is printed followed by the 
   * character in the map location.
   * @param map The map to print out.
   */
  public static void simplePrintMap(char[][] map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + map[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    return; //Prints out a map without labels
  }

  /**
   * This prints out the map. This shows numbers of the columns
   * and rows on the top and left side, respectively. 
   * map[0][0] is row 1, column 1 when shown to the user.
   * The first column, last column and every multiple of 5 are shown.
   * 
   * To print out a 2 digit number with a leading space if the number
   * is less than 10, you may use:
   *     System.out.printf("%2d", 1); 
   * 
   * @param map The map to print out.
   */
  public static void printMap(char[][] map) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) { //prints out the labels for columns)
      if (j == 0) {
        System.out.print("   1");
      } else if (j == map.length - 1) {
        System.out.printf("%2d", (j + 1));
      } else if ((j + 1) % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%2d", (j + 1));
      } else {
        System.out.print("--");
      }


    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) { //prints out labels for rows and the map
      if (i == 0) {
        System.out.print(" 1");
      } else if (i == map.length - 1) {
        System.out.printf("%2d", (i + 1));
      } else if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%2d", (i + 1));
      } else {
        System.out.print(" |");
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
        if (map[i][j] == Config.NO_NEARBY_MINE) {
          System.out.print(" T " + (map[i][j]));
        } else {
          System.out.print(" " + (map[i][j]));
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    return; //prints out a map with row and column labels
  }

  /**
   * This method initializes the boolean mines array passed in. A true value for
   * an element in the mines array means that location has a mine, false means
   * the location does not have a mine. The MINE_PROBABILITY is used to determine
   * whether a particular location has a mine. The randGen parameter contains the
   * reference to the instance of Random created in the main method.
   * 
   * Access the elements in the mines array with row then column (e.g., mines[row][col]).
   * 
   * Access the elements in the array solely using the actual size of the mines
   * array passed in, do not use constants. 
   * 
   * A MINE_PROBABILITY of 0.3 indicates that a particular location has a
   * 30% chance of having a mine.  For each location the result of
   *      randGen.nextFloat() < Config.MINE_PROBABILITY 
   * determines whether that location has a mine.
   * 
   * This method does not print out anything.
   *  
   * @param mines  The array of boolean that tracks the locations of the mines.
   * @param randGen The reference to the instance of the Random number generator
   *      created in the main method.
   * @return The number of mines in the mines array.
   */
  public static int placeMines(boolean[][] mines, Random randGen) {
    int mineCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mines.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mines[0].length; j++) {
        if (randGen.nextFloat() < Config.MINE_PROBABILITY) {
          mines[i][j] = true;
          ++mineCount;
        }
      }
    }
    return mineCount; //returns the total count of mines on the map
  }

  /**
   * This method returns the number of mines in the 8 neighboring locations.
   * For locations along an edge of the array, neighboring locations outside of 
   * the mines array do not contain mines. This method does not print out anything.
   * 
   * If the row or col arguments are outside the mines array, then return -1.
   * This method (or any part of this program) should not use exception handling.
   * 
   * @param mines The array showing where the mines are located.
   * @param row The row, 0-based, of a location.
   * @param col The col, 0-based, of a location.
   * @return The number of mines in the 8 surrounding locations or -1 if row or col
   *      are invalid.
   */
  public static int numNearbyMines(boolean[][] mines, int row, int col) {
    int mineCount = 0;
    if (row == 0) { //checks all the fields for a field in the first row
      if (col == 0) {
        if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      } else if (col == mines[0].length - 1) {
        if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }

        if (mines[row + 1][col - 1]) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      } else {
        if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col - 1]) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      }
    } else if (row == mines.length - 1) { //checks all the fields for a field in the last row
      if (col == 0) {
        if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      } else if (col == mines[0].length - 1) {
        if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      } else {
        if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      }
    } else { //check all the fields for a field not in the first or the last row
      if (col == 0) {
        if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      } else if (col == mines[0].length - 1) {
        if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
      } else {
        if (mines[row - 1][col] == true) {
          ++mineCount;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row - 1][col + 1]) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col - 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row + 1][col - 1]) {
          mineCount++;
        }
        if (mines[row][col + 1] == true) {
          mineCount++;
        }

      }
    }
    return mineCount; //returns the number of mines in the spots next to user picked spot
  }

  /**
   * This updates the map with each unswept mine shown with the Config.HIDDEN_MINE
   * character. Swept mines will already be mapped and so should not be changed.
   * This method does not print out anything.
   * 
   * @param map  An array containing the map. On return the map shows unswept mines.
   * @param mines An array indicating which locations have mines.  No changes
   *      are made to the mines array.
   */
  public static void showMines(char[][] map, boolean[][] mines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mines.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mines[0].length; j++) {
        if (map[i][j] == Config.SWEPT_MINE) {
          map[i][j] = Config.SWEPT_MINE;
        } else if (mines[i][j] == true) {
          map[i][j] = Config.HIDDEN_MINE;
        }
      }
    }
    return; //updates the map array to show uncovered mines
  }

  /**
   * Returns whether all the safe (non-mine) locations have been swept. In 
   * other words, whether all unswept locations have mines. 
   * This method does not print out anything.
   * 
   * @param map The map showing touched locations that is unchanged by this method.
   * @param mines The mines array that is unchanged by this method.
   * @return whether all non-mine locations are swept.
   */
  public static boolean allSafeLocationsSwept(char[][] map, boolean[][] mines) {
    boolean allSafeSwept = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < mines.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < mines[0].length; j++) {
        if (mines[i][j] == false && map[i][j] == Config.UNSWEPT) {
          allSafeSwept = false;
        }
      }
    }
    return allSafeSwept; //returns true if all safe locations have been swept

  }

  /**
   * This method sweeps the specified row and col.
   *   - If the row and col specify a location outside the map array then 
   *     return -3 without changing the map.***
   *   - If the location has already been swept then return -2 without changing
   *     the map.
   *   - If there is a mine in the location then the map for the corresponding
   *     location is updated with Config.SWEPT_MINE and return -1.
   *   - If there is not a mine then the number of nearby mines is determined 
   *     by calling the numNearbyMines method. 
   *        - If there are 1 to 8 nearby mines then the map is updated with 
   *          the characters '1'..'8' indicating the number of nearby mines.
   *        - If the location has 0 nearby mines then the map is updated with
   *          the Config.NO_NEARBY_MINE character.
   *        - Return the number of nearbyMines.
   *        
   * @param map The map showing swept locations.
   * @param mines The array showing where the mines are located.
   * @param row The row, 0-based, of a location.
   * @param col The col, 0-based, of a location.
   * @return the number of nearby mines, -1 if the location is a mine, -2 if 
   * the location has already been swept, -3 if the location is off the map.
   */
  public static int sweepLocation(char[][] map, boolean[][] mines, int row, int col) {
    int nearbyMines = 0;
    char nearbyMinesChar = 'x'; //returns -3 if the user spot is out of range of the array
    if (row < 0 || row >= map.length || col < 0 || col >= map[0].length) {
      return -3;
    } else if (map[row][col] != Config.UNSWEPT) { //returns -2 if user spot has been previously swept
      return -2;
    } else if (mines[row][col] == true) { //returns -1 if there is a mine in the user spot
      map[row][col] = Config.SWEPT_MINE;
      return -1;
    } else if (mines[row][col] == false) { //checks for number of mines if the user spot has not been previously swept
      nearbyMines = numNearbyMines(mines, row, col);
      if (nearbyMines >= 1 || nearbyMines <= 8) { //if there is at least one mine nearby returns number of mines
        nearbyMinesChar = Character.forDigit(nearbyMines, nearbyMines + 1);
        map[row][col] = nearbyMinesChar;
      } else if (nearbyMines == 0) { //if there are no nearby mines sets map to NO_NEARBY_MINE
        map[row][col] = Config.NO_NEARBY_MINE;
      }
      return nearbyMines;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * This method iterates through all 8 neighboring locations and calls sweepLocation
   * for each. It does not call sweepLocation for its own location, just the neighboring
   * locations.
   * @param map The map showing touched locations.
   * @param mines The array showing where the mines are located.
   * @param row The row, 0-based, of a location.
   * @param col The col, 0-based, of a location.
   */
  public static void sweepAllNeighbors(char[][] map, boolean[][] mines, int row, int col) {
    if (row == 0) { //Calls sweep location for all the locations in the first row
      if (col == 0) {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col + 1);
      } else if (col == mines[0].length - 1) {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col - 1);
      } else {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col + 1);
      }
    } else if (row == mines.length - 1) { //Calls sweep location for all the locations in the last row
      if (col == 0) {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col + 1);
      } else if (col == mines[0].length - 1) {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col);
      } else {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col + 1);
      }
    } else { //Calls sweep location for all the locations in not in the first or last row
      if (col == 0) {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col);
      } else if (col == mines[0].length - 1) {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col);
      } else {
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row - 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col + 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row + 1, col - 1);
        sweepLocation(map, mines, row, col + 1);
      }
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

This code should behave as follows:

[image: code]

However when I run it, it shifts my lines.

[image: it shifts my lines]

I've been trying to change the spacing for a few hours now and I'm hitting a wall. I thought maybe adding an if statement will help. Keep in min that what's inserted is a constant (which is just a space) - I know there are some deficiencies in the code and it could be improved but I'm focusing on trying to get it working correctly - any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line in `sweepLocation`:

```
if (nearbyMines >= 1 || nearbyMines <= 8) { //if there is at least one mine nearby returns number of mines
```

When is the condition in this `if` statement true?

The answer is that it  is always true!  Any number is either at least 1 **or** at most 8 (or both).  Check it if you don't believe me!

You probably wanted to check that `nearbyMines` was at least 1 **and** at most 8.  You would do that by replacing `||` with `&&`, i.e.:

```
if (nearbyMines >= 1 && nearbyMines <= 8) { //if there is at least one mine nearby returns number of mines
```

The reason the lines in the grid were being shifted is due to this line:

```
    nearbyMinesChar = Character.forDigit(nearbyMines, nearbyMines + 1);
```

The second argument to `Character.forDigit` is the 'radix', or the number base, of the digit.  If the radix is out of range (and the range happens to be 2 to 36), then this method returns the null character instead.  If `nearbyMines` was zero, you ended up passing 1 for the radix, which is outside of the range and hence you got back a null character.  The lines ended up being shifted because printing the null character does nothing.

I really don't see why you're passing `nearbyMines + 1` for the radix here; it would be simpler to just use `10`, as all the digits are in base 10.

After making these changes to your code, it seemed to work more as I would expect it to, in that the problem with shifting lines had gone.  (I couldn't reproduce your grid exactly, but that's because I don't know what value you've set `Config.SEED` to.  For me anyway, setting the seed to zero gave me a grid with no mines, which was enough to reproduce your problem.)